# MongoDB Sort Documents by Values in Array

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have a collection that contains an optional Array. This Array can then contain Strings (but will be an enum essentially).

i.e.

```
123: {
   foo: 'bar',
   arr: ['fizz','buzz']
},
456: {
   foo:'bar',
},
789: {
   foo: 'bar',
   arr: ['fizz']
},
000: {
    foo:'bar',
    arr:['buzz']
}
```

I'd like to sort these doce by any value in `arr`. I.e. If I want to sort by possible 'buzz' values in any existing `arr` Then, I'd expect to see 123 & 000 at the top.

Is this possible? I tried `{sort: {arr:{'buzz':1}}}` but that does not work. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You have numbers like `123` as field names so are they dynamic?

Comment: @DheemanthBhat no, the numbers don't mean anything here, just sample key names for the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** based on comments

Query:

```js
let input = "buzz";

db.collectionName.find(
    {
        $or: [
            { $text: { $search: input } },
            { _id: { $exists: true } }
        ]
    },
    {
        "foo": 1,
        score: { $meta: "textScore" }
    }
).sort({ 
    score: { $meta: "textScore" }
});
```

**IMPORTANT**: You need to create [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index) as shown below:

```js
db.collectionName.insertMany([
    /* 1 createdAt:2/25/2021, 2:14:03 AM*/
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("6036ba93e715d911e89e062b"),
        "foo": "bar4",
        "arr": ["buzz"]
    },

    /* 2 createdAt:2/25/2021, 2:14:03 AM*/
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("6036ba93e715d911e89e062a"),
        "foo": "bar3",
        "arr": ["fizz"]
    },

    /* 3 createdAt:2/25/2021, 2:14:03 AM*/
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("6036ba93e715d911e89e0629"),
        "foo": "bar2"
    },

    /* 4 createdAt:2/25/2021, 2:14:03 AM*/
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("6036ba93e715d911e89e0628"),
        "foo": "bar1",
        "arr": ["fizz", "buzz"]
    }
]);

db.collectionName.createIndex({ arr: "text" });
```

Output:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:2/25/2021, 2:14:03 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036ba93e715d911e89e0628"),
    "foo" : "bar1",
    "score" : 1.1
},

/* 2 createdAt:2/25/2021, 2:14:03 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036ba93e715d911e89e062b"),
    "foo" : "bar4",
    "score" : 1.1
},

/* 3 createdAt:2/25/2021, 2:14:03 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036ba93e715d911e89e0629"),
    "foo" : "bar2"
},

/* 4 createdAt:2/25/2021, 2:14:03 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036ba93e715d911e89e062a"),
    "foo" : "bar3"
}
```

Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66275959/how-to-get-the-number-of-occurence-of-a-keyword-inside-a-string-using-mongodb) for some insights on `textScore`.

**OLD ANSWER**

Try this:

```js
let input = "buzz";

db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "foo": 1,
            "sortArray": {
                $size: {
                    $ifNull: [
                        {
                            $filter: {
                                input: "$arr",
                                as: "item",
                                cond: { $in: [input, "$arr"] }
                            }
                        },
                        []
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { sortArray: -1 }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:2/25/2021, 2:14:03 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036ba93e715d911e89e0628"),
    "foo" : "bar1",
    "sortArray" : 2
},

/* 2 createdAt:2/25/2021, 2:14:03 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036ba93e715d911e89e062b"),
    "foo" : "bar4",
    "sortArray" : 1
},

/* 3 createdAt:2/25/2021, 2:14:03 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036ba93e715d911e89e0629"),
    "foo" : "bar2",
    "sortArray" : 0
},

/* 4 createdAt:2/25/2021, 2:14:03 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036ba93e715d911e89e062a"),
    "foo" : "bar3",
    "sortArray" : 0
}
```

My test data looks like this:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:2/25/2021, 2:14:03 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036ba93e715d911e89e062b"),
    "foo" : "bar4",
    "arr" : ["buzz"]
},

/* 2 createdAt:2/25/2021, 2:14:03 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036ba93e715d911e89e062a"),
    "foo" : "bar3",
    "arr" : ["fizz"]
},

/* 3 createdAt:2/25/2021, 2:14:03 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036ba93e715d911e89e0629"),
    "foo" : "bar2"
},

/* 4 createdAt:2/25/2021, 2:14:03 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036ba93e715d911e89e0628"),
    "foo" : "bar1",
    "arr" : ["fizz", "buzz"]
}
```

Comment: I love your solution, it's very clever. I adopted the same approach of introducing another variable (your `sortByArray`) - but in straight JS in post-processing upon retrieving from Mongo.

This is because I cannot use Aggregate in the framework I'm using (Meteor). It's because I need to retain reactivity.

Do you know of any way to solve this without an aggregate? Thanks!

Comment: By straight JS I meant just plain old javascript. I.e. I retrieve results of all Objects in one regular Mongo `find` - then post-process in JS

Comment: Check if this helps: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GO2G6SCU67A6 .So once u get the documents from database, use that logic inside node.js. if in case u are not able to access let me know

Comment: Thanks, I had something similar to what you did in that link. I was just wondering if there was any way to achieve the sort without JS and without a Mongo Aggregate. So - just using a regular Mongo `find` or something similar

Comment: "MongoDB amazes me every day! and SO helps in doing this!" :) Check the updated answer.

Comment: Ah, sorting by score! Very neat. I'll have to consider that. Don't know if I'm going to add an index just yet